# Installing scipy on virtual environment

Tags: python, scipy

Using pip install scipy --no-cache-dir according to instructions given [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/18/keras-deep-learning-raspberry-pi/) on a raspberry py 3 and installing all dependencies get the following error:

```
Command "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3P2/bin/python2 -u -c "import 
setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-
N75NAu/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', 
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record 
/tmp/pip-record-VRjb6r/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile --install-headers 
/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3P2/include/site/python2.7/scipy" failed with 
error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-N75NAu/scipy/
```

Any help will be appreciated.